# Is it possible to Create combined audiences from simple audience ( Remarketing Audiences ) in google analytics managment API?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-filters

I'm building a new script that takes data from a spreadsheet and create audiences using the google analytics management API. the problem that I'm facing is that when we create these audiences often we need to combine some of them into one audience.
Example: we create an audience that has 14 days as membership duration days
AND an audience that has 7 days as membership duration days.

the audience that has 14 will include the users that are listed in the audience that has 7 days and we avoid that by creating a combined List that includes one List and exclude the other but I haven't found a way tp create these lists in doc. can you please tell me if this is available through the API, is so can you refer me to the docs?

Thank you

Comment: Have you looked at using the [`stateBasedAudienceDefinition`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/remarketingAudience#resource) You can define two different segments. `SEGMENT_14` and `SEGMENT_7` then within the `stateBasedAudienceDefinition. have the `SEGMENT_14` in the `includeConditions` and `SEGMENT_7` in the `excludeConditions `

Comment: Thanks @Matt, but the problem with that is you can use exclude one List. Because segments are limited to 10 conditions. and we usually have 8 lists each with 5 to 6 conditions. And the Combined ( List ) will include one and exclude the other 7. so if we go with segments I'm afraid it won't be possible ( Based on my knowledge ). Please correct me If I'm wrong. that Is why i'm asking if there a way to create an audience ( List ) from other audiences ( Lists ).